# Telegram bot: customise buttons position on keyboard

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Is there a way to customise buttons position on keyboard?

Example: we have

```
import telegram

def start(bot, update):

    kb = [[telegram.KeyboardButton('/command1')],
          [telegram.KeyboardButton('/command2')],
          [telegram.KeyboardButton('/command3')]]
    kb_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(kb, resize_keyboard=True)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                     text="Welcome!",
                     reply_markup=kb_markup)
```

As the result we have keyboard with 3 buttons, each button on its own row.

I would like to have 2 button on the first row and 1 button on the second row. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

yes, of course!

```
[[button1, button2],
 [button3]]
```

each row in the overall list corresponds to one row on the kb